# Canonicalize products to category?

Tags: canonical-url, rel-canonical

There is an ecommerce site, a category and products. Some few products are top, most other products are so-so.

Is it a good idea to canonicalize so-so products to category?

Like this

- Category: https://example.com/category1.html
- Top product: https://example.com/category1/top-product-1.html - remains with self-referencing canonical
- So-so product: https://example.com/category1/soso-product-2.html gets `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/category1.html" />`

Answer (score 1):

No, the role of canonicalization is pointing URLs that are mostly similar to a proper *canonical* one.  That's not the case here.

Determine what makes a product "so-so" vs "top" and see if it can be changed. For example, maybe so-so products have thin content, that is something you can change. If the products are just unappealing then that is a problem for the business to solve by making better products.

Comment: so-so products just make low or no revenue, earn low or no traffic. Between *low* and *no* there is a gap, which prevents a definite noindex decision. If I correctly understand your point, it is in these terms better to canonicalize products to products, as to category. I admit, my idea is a kind of misuse of canonical. I just think, whether it could be effective.

Comment: What are you hoping to make happen?